# Database server issue while deploying Jenkins

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, jenkins

I created 3 servers for Tomcat (ip is x.x.x.10), web (ip is x.x.x.11) and db (ip is x.x.x.12). These 3 are co-ordinating manually. I gave full access to Tomcat server to create tables in database server. If I'm connecting manually from tomcat server to database server, it is working perfectly.

Then I created a Jenkins job for deploy war on Tomcat server.

In my svn server, I kept database server (x.x.x.12) info in "jdbc.properties" file and committed. My "jdbc.properties" file looks like below.

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl = jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.12:3306/epsilon
jdbc.username = mysql 
jdbc.password = mypassword
```

Then I'm running job on Jenkins to build war and deploy on Tomcat server. Jenkins not showing any errors and job ran successfully.

But in Tomcat server catalina.log file showing that there is no permission to create database on x.x.x.10. But I kept x.x.x.12 in "jdbc.properties" file. Why Tomcat server assumig that as a database server is it self and why it is not considering "jdbc.properties" file.

I removed Jenkins workspace and job plugins. But still issue is same.

Answer (score 0):

You should review your build process and the generated binaries to make sure that the application package (ear, war, whatever) contains precisely the properties file you have pasted and not a local development version.

For example, if you had a Maven project based on profiles (LOCAL, AVE, UAT, etc.) and you had built a binary specifying LOCAL profile instead of any other, then you would be finding similar effects when trying to deploy it to your tomcat server.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Jorge. I will follow your steps, and I will keep issues here, If I faced any.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found root cause for this. I.E., spaces issue in configuration file. While creating your jdbc.properties file with scripts / manually please check spaces at last of your values. Don't keep any space for db username and pass and db hosts name etc..